# VUEjs templates multiple selectboxes

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, vue-component

So, I'm assigned to work with vue at work, but VUE and I aren't friends yet. Currently I'm facing an issue that I don't know how to resolve - I'll explain it the best I can with the limited VUE knowledge I possess.

Simplistically I have a vue component, which looks like this:

```
Vue.component('input-checkboxes', {
    template: '#input_checkboxes',
    props: ['id', 'label', 'list', 'required', 'readonly']
});
```

Then I have a template that looks like this:

```
 <template id="input_checkboxes">

    <div>
        <div>{{ label }}</div>
        <div>

            <label v-for="list_item in list">

                <input type="checkbox" v-model="value" :name="id" :required="required" :readonly="readonly" value="{{ list_item.name }}"> {{ list_item.name }}
            </label>

        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

Then I have a rather large vue instance that I'll paste the relevant parts of here.

This variable is being created:

```
var some_form = {
    form : {
        Endless: '',
        Amounts: '',
        Of: '',
        Names: '',
        In: '',
        The: '',
        Form: '',
        THIS-ONE: ''
    }
};


var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#form_product',
    data: $.extend({
        someStuff : 'some values',
        someLists : {}
    }, some_form),
    ready: function() {
         this.getLists(); // Fetches alot of lists
    },
    methods: {
        this.$http.get(
            framework.url('api','getLookupLists')
        ).then(function (response) {

            this.lists = response.body;
            this.pageLoading = false;
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

In the end I have my html page that amongst loads of other fields, that works very well, has this:

```
<input-checkboxes
    id="THIS-ONE"
    label="A Fitting Label"
    :value.sync="form.SomeID"
    :list="lists.AnAppropriateList">
</input-checkboxes>
```

So, that's the gist of the setup. I have numerous other components like input-text, that works just fine (someone else made it before I did), I even created other components by copying his way, and just changing some elements.

I cannot get checkboxes to work, I think my problem is that there are numerous inputs, and that I don't know how to bind the results of those inputs to my VUE instance.

I really hope this makes sense, because I would really like some pointers on how to get on... Maybe if someone duplicated this setup really simplistic and showed how the array of values from the checkboxes could be bound to the vue instance?

Comment: What isn't binding? What's the output? Could you set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes you are (or might be) making.

1. First of all, the value prop you pass down has to be an array (seems
   like it's a string from your example)
2. `value` is not correctly set, you need to set it by doing `:value="someValue"`; you can't have curlies in an attribute.
3. Lastly, value should probably be the id of the item and not the name. You have a chance of a collision if you use the name.

   - Bonus: you don't need to use `:name` at all (unless you are submitting the form server side...? But I can't see why you would do that.)

Here's a simple working example to sum this up:

**HTML**

```
<label v-for="list_item in list">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="value" :required="required" :readonly="readonly" :value="list_item.id"> {{ list_item.name }}
</label>
```

**JS**

```
var app = new Vue({ 
  el: 'main', 
  data: function () { 
    return { 
      value: [],
      label: 'Label name',
      readonly: false,
      required: true,
      list: [
        {
          name: 'Item 1',
          id: 'item1'
        },
        {
          name: 'Item 2',
          id: 'item2'
        }
      ]
    }
  } 
})
```

I've also made [a bin](https://jsbin.com/pazuxi/10/edit?html,js,output) for you to try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look at it - but I'm very hung up at work today, so It'll be a few days, sorry about that...